# What does 다할 from 다하다 mean and what is '-ㄹ' after '다하'?

Tags: grammar, verb-endings

I came across this sentence 힘이 다할 때까지 which means as I understood "until (your) strength runs out". 힘이 means power/strength, and once I looked for 다할, it says it comes from the verb 다하다.

But what does the '-ㄹ' stands for after '다하'?
I need more explanation about this verb and '-ㄹ' and its uses and if possible a few examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's one of attributive endings (`관형 어미`) which transform a predicate (verbs, adjectives) into a modifier of the following noun. When attached to a sentence, they make the sentence something like a relative clause in English.

There are four common attributive endings `-ㄴ/-은`, `-ㄹ/-을`, `-던`, and `-는`. They express different tense and aspect/modal.

`-ㄴ/-은` implies a true statement, meaning that X DOES actually have the property of what the predicate states. Can roughly be mapped into present perfect in English - something happened in the past and still effective.

> - 존이 집에 *간* 것을 알고 있어요? 
>    Do you know the fact that John has gone back to home?
> - 활짝 *핀* 꽃 
>    fully bloomed flower
> - 깨끗*한* 책상 
>    a neat desk

while `-ㄹ/-을` attributes possibility, meaning that X may or will have the property. Adjectives do **not** go with `-ㄹ/-을`

> - 존이 집에 *갈* 것을 알고 있어요? 
>    Do you know that John will go back to home?
> - 그런 일이 일어나면 존이 집에 *갈* 것을 알고 있어요? 
>    Are you aware that, in such a case, John may leave to home?
> - 활짝 필 꽃봉우리 
>    a bud that will bloom

`-던` attributes some property that was true at some point in the past, but not likely at present. Can be roughly mapped into past perfect, or past progress.

> - 여기가 수잔이 살*던* 집이다. 
>    This is the place where Susan used to live. (she doesn't any more.)
> - 깨끗하*던* 책상 
>    a desk that were neat

Finally, `-는`. It's the attributive form from the present tense sentential ending (`종결 어미`) `-ㄴ다/-는다`. So it can express

- something happens now
- something is determined to happen soon
- something happens habitually

You can think of present tense in English, and they will mostly fit. And again, adjectives do **not** go with this.

Comment: much better answer than mine!!

Comment: Note that ㄴ is used to express relative clauses that were done in the past. For present tense, we should use 는 which is also common.

Comment: So as I understood from your explanation, I'd say the sentence 힘이 다할 때까지 it literally means " until one's strength will end " ? .aren't those attributive endings related to time; -ㄴ when talking about something happened in the past and -ㄹ used when something might or will happen? isn't? I'd like to make sure that I understood well. thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @SCHGB: Added `-는` to the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Sarah Chaygani: Yes, you can think their differences on the time frame, in case of verbs/relative clauses.

Comment: @Krim Alright,감사합니다!

Answer (score 3):

(Disclaimer: I'm not an expert in Korean grammar, but just a native speaker.)

It transforms a verb into an **adjective form that qualifies the following noun**. In the case of "다할 때", it qualifies "때" which means time. "다할 때" therefore means "the time when (*) runs out".

Another example would be "마를 때", which comes from "마르다" (to dry) + "때". It means "time at which (it) dries".

The noun "수" which means "case" or "possibility" can also come after verb-ㄹ form. For example, "힘이 다할 수도 있다" would mean "strength could run out"; and "마를 수도 있다" means "(it) could dry out".

More examples:

- 갈 방법이 없다: there's no way to go (가다 (to go) -> 갈)
- 죽지 않을 수만 있다면: only if I could not die (않다 (not) -> 않을)
- 막을 도리가 없다: there's no way to block it (막다 (to block) -> 막을)