# 공항 가는 길 or 가까이 사는 집

Tags: grammar

Given that

> 후세인 회사에 다닌다.

We can say the below about Husain.

> 후세인 회사에 다니는 사람인다.

Where 회사에 다니는 is an attributive verb modifying 사람.

How can one use 공항 가는 and 가까이 사는 as attributive verbs to 길 and 집, respectively?

> 공항 간다 -> (길)
>
> 가까이 산다 -> (집)

I don't think that the two attributive verbs are derived from the above two sentences because I'm sure they are wrong.

Comment: may i suggest an edit?

Comment: @WEBjuju sure go a head

Comment: in your question, are you making some question that requires a relationship or reference binding `공항 가는 길` to `가까이 사는 집`?  or are they mostly random examples of making adjective phrases (attributive verbs)?

Comment: Two different examples that have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1

First off, you probably don't want to say

> 후세인 회사에 다닌다.

to say about Husain, if what you want to say is

> Husain goes to a/the company.

, because then you would end up with saying either

> (Someone in context) goes to a company named Husain.

or

> (Someone in context) goes to a company owned by Husain.

In Korean, noun-noun sequence is tend to be interpreted as the preceding one modifies the following one. Thus, in this case, `후세인 회사` is most likely either `Husain's company` or literally `Husain Co.`
(Just like `Trump administration`, a noun-noun combo)

You should use case marker `은/는` or `이/가` to specifically say that Husain is the subject who goes to the company, as such,

> 후세인은 회사에 다닌다.
>
> 후세인은 회사에 다니는 사람이다. (회사원이다)

## 2

Now move on to the question. Attributive ending `ㄴ/는` works somewhat similar (but not exactly the same) to relative clauses in English, in that it makes the embedded verb (verb with the `ㄴ/는` ending) to modify the following noun (**note that** a relative clause in English follows the noun, whereas in Korean the noun follows).
That being said, you can transliterate the above like this;

> 후세인은 회사에 다니는 사람이다.
>
> Husain is a person who goes to the company.

Thus both

> 공항 가는 길
>
> the way that leads to the airport (= way to airport)

and

> 가까이 사는 집 (`집` here means a family, not a house)
>
> a family that lives around (= a neighbor)

make perfect sense.

Here are a couple examples

> 후세인이 공항 가는 길에 전화했어요
>
> Husain called on his way to the airport
>
> 후세인은 가까이 사는 집들이랑 친하다면서요?
>
> I heard Husain does get along with his neighbors.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very crystal clear answer plus some tip on top.

Comment: My pleasure! See my answer [here](http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/what-does-%EB%8B%A4%ED%95%A0-from-%EB%8B%A4%ED%95%98%EB%8B%A4-mean-and-what-is-%E3%84%B9-after-%EB%8B%A4%ED%95%98/1810#1810) for other attributive endings.

Answer (score 3):

You can use use 공항 가는 as an attributive verb (adjective) for 길 as well as using 가까이 사는 as an attributive verb (adjective) for 집:

> 공항가는 길이다
>
> 회사에서 가까이 사는 집이 좋다

*But the second one is still a little awkward since 가깝다 is it's own verb anyway, so you should probably say*

> 회사에서 가까운 집이 좋다